# Control not working on first click after jquery function

Tags: jquery

I have an `<asp:listbox>`. I converted it to lists (`li` with checkboxes) using jQuery. I added validation so that if no checkbox is selected then I am showing this div (div with lists). Everything is ok till now, but after the listbox works on double click (it does nothing on first click).

I used the below jQuery:

```
var a = $(".shortddl").find("ul input:checked").length;     
if (a == 0) {                     
    alert("Please Select Qualification");
    $('input.whiteback').focus();                  
}
```

HTML:-

```
  <asp:ListBox ID="ddlQualification" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" Height="0" Style="overflow: auto;" CssClass="mylist"></asp:ListBox>&nbsp&nbsp
```

Comment: And the question is.... ?

Comment: provide some html please.. and the code causing unexpected behavior. thx

Comment: And how is the code above called?